# Laravel Mix cant compile asset when install laravel jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-jetstream

After I follow step by step in the documentation to install Laravel Jetstream and then go to step:
https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

After I run that, I am stuck and get the following errors.

> ```
> > adminportofolio@1.0.0 dev /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio
> > npm run development
>
>
> > adminportofolio@1.0.0 development /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio
> > mix
>
>
> ✖ Mix
>   Compiled with some errors in 90.23ms
>
> ERROR in ../../../#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/resources/js/app.js
> Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js'
> Require stack:
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
>     at require (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>     at /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
>     at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10),
> ```
>
> :7:1)
> at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
> at NormalModule.doBuild (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:24)
> at NormalModule.build (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:910:15)
> at /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1312:12
>
> ```
> ERROR in ../../../#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/resources/css/app.css
> Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js'
> Require stack:
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
> - /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
>     at require (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>     at /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js:412:9
>     at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10),
> ```
>
> :7:1)
> at NormalModule.doBuild (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:24)
> at NormalModule.build (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:910:15)
> at /mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1312:12
> at NormalModule.needBuild (/mnt/d/#Ricky_Only/Code/adminPortofolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1179:32)
>
> ```
> webpack compiled with 2 errors
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! adminportofolio@1.0.0 development: `mix`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the adminportofolio@1.0.0 development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/msi/.npm/_logs/2021-06-03T13_12_58_493Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! adminportofolio@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the adminportofolio@1.0.0 dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/msi/.npm/_logs/2021-06-03T13_12_58_517Z-debug.log
> ```

this is my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
    
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Mix Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
     | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
     | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
     |
     */
    
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
        .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss'),
        ])
        .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
    
    if (mix.inProduction()) {
        mix.version();
    }
```

this is my [package.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGsKSvEv8gxuuN6i9XxuBEVC9wgiH3BI/view?usp=sharing) file

Comment: Show us your `webpack.mix.js` and `package.json` files